# Server & Client Always Not responding

Tags: c#, sockets, freeze

I'm new to sockets so I tried to create a server and a client that exchange messages. I created one in C# but it gave me weird error which it once I start the server it freezes and "not responding" message appears ... same happens with client when I connect the server but the problem is when I close any of them .. the other application have the updates shown up so idk what the problem is anyways here are the codes U used

Server class

```
Socket Soc;
static ushort MaxClients = 1000;
static List<Socket> ClientList = new List<Socket>(MaxClients);
static bool ServerStarted;
public Server()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Send
{
    string MessageToSend = textBox1.Text;
    byte[] Buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MessageToSend);
    foreach (var client in ClientList)
    {
        Soc.Send(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
    textBox2.Text += " Message Sent To Clients : " + MessageToSend + Environment.NewLine;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start
{
    StartServer("25.21.113.163", 5000);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Stop
{
    CloseServer();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Exit
{
    CloseServer();
    Application.Exit();
}

public void StartServer(string Ip, ushort Port)
{
    Soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Soc.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), Port));
    textBox2.Text += " Server Is Created On Ip : " + Ip + ", Port : " + Port + Environment.NewLine;
    Soc.Listen(MaxClients);
    textBox2.Text += " Server Is Listening to Clients Now... " + Environment.NewLine;
    ServerStarted = true;
    button1.Enabled = true;
    button2.Enabled = true;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    label3.Text = ClientList.Count.ToString() + "/" + MaxClients;
    ReceiveData();
}

public void ReceiveData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var Client = Soc.Accept();
        ClientList.Add(Client);
        label3.Text = ClientList.Count.ToString() + "/" + MaxClients;
        textBox2.Text += " Client Located At Ip : " + Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0].ToString() + " Is Now Connected To Server " + Environment.NewLine;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int ReceivedDataLength = Client.Receive(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            string MessageFromClient = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedDataLength);
            textBox2.Text += " Message Sent to Server : " + MessageFromClient + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}

public void CloseServer()
{
    Soc.Close();
    ServerStarted = false;
    textBox2.Text += " Server Is Closed Now... " + Environment.NewLine;
    button3.Enabled = true;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Client class

```
Socket Client;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Send
{
    string MessageToSend = textBox2.Text;
    byte[] Buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MessageToSend);
    Client.Send(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    textBox1.Text += " Sent Message To Server Is : " + MessageToSend + Environment.NewLine;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // LogOut
{
    ClientClose();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Connect
{
    ConnectToServer("25.21.113.163", 5000);
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Exit
{
    ClientClose();
    Application.Exit();
}

public void ConnectToServer(string Ip, ushort Port)
{
    try
    {
        Client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Client.Connect(Ip, Port);
        textBox1.Text += " You Are Now Connected To Server Hosted On Ip : " + Client.RemoteEndPoint + Environment.NewLine;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        ReceiveData();
    }
    catch
    {
        textBox1.Text += " Server In Offline Now " + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

public void ReceiveData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[1024];
        int ReceivedBytesLength = Client.Receive(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        string ReceivedMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytesLength);
        textBox1.Text += " Received Message From Server Is : " + ReceivedMessage + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

public void ClientClose()
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = true;
    Client.Dispose();
    Client.Close();
    textBox1.Text += " You Are Disconnected From Server" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

I'd like to know what did I do wrong? And how can I get rid of that silly "Not Responding" state of both applications?

Answer (score 0):

First, Let's make a corrections on your code so that it works, thank I'd give some `Asynchronous Socket` tutorials which is a lot easier than `Synchronous`.

Your problem is in this line:

```
public void ReceiveData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var Client = Soc.Accept();
        ClientList.Add(Client);
        label3.Text = ClientList.Count.ToString() + "/" + MaxClients;
        textBox2.Text += " Client Located At Ip : " + Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0].ToString() + " Is Now Connected To Server " + Environment.NewLine;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int ReceivedDataLength = Client.Receive(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            string MessageFromClient = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedDataLength);
            textBox2.Text += " Message Sent to Server : " + MessageFromClient + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

This is because of 2 reasons:
1) You must listen to incoming connection to a separate thread.
2) You must listen to each client in a separate thread too, so they don't block each other. In your example second `while(true)` which is listening for client is blocking server socket from accepting other clients. Refactor it to:

```
public void ReceiveData()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var Client = Soc.Accept();
                ClientList.Add(Client);
                label3.Text = ClientList.Count.ToString() + "/" + MaxClients;
                textBox2.Text += " Client Located At Ip : " + Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0].ToString() + " Is Now Connected To Server " + Environment.NewLine;

                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[1024];
                        int ReceivedDataLength = Client.Receive(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        string MessageFromClient = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedDataLength);
                        textBox2.Text += " Message Sent to Server : " + MessageFromClient + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }).Start();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

This approach uses separate thread for each client to process received data from client.

I also added code for client app:

```
public void ReceiveData()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[1024];
                int ReceivedBytesLength = Client.Receive(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                string ReceivedMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytesLength);
                textBox1.Text += " Received Message From Server Is : " + ReceivedMessage + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

In the future have a look `Asynchronous Sockets` and you will no more need handling multithreading issues.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx

*EDIT* Updated client/ser

Comment: well the Server Application hang up and become not responding after starting it .. without even getting a client connection .. same goes for client once i press connect it become freezed too and all the sending / receving messages are working but u dont see that except when you close any of them .. you see the other application updated ..i dont know if Sync Socket is desgined to be that stupid but i dont care much about Syncs and would never use em but all i need to know is y the Applications are hanging up

Comment: Copy updated code. Note: You will receive error when updating TextBox values from other than UI thread, but simple googling will help ;)

Comment: it did a good job but when i send the client Text it give me an error saying that no Address was given idk what that means seems everything is going correctly

Another question if i used Async socket will i have to call while (true) or it handles everything related to Threading ?

Comment: Replace 25.21.113.163 with localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: When using Async sockets you subscribe to particular event of socket, say Received, and call ReceiveAsync on socket and forget about it. When sockets receives data, corresponding event will be fired.